# User registration & login in Hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am working on a project where I need the functionality of user registration and user login. I need some suggestion. What would be the better way of achieving this task?

> **A.) Old school email & password OR 
> B.) By using public & private keys?**

What I understand from option B is that we need to enroll a user from `CA` from `Fabric-SDK`. Once enrolment of user is done, we can generate a unique `password-phrase` like the same is happening in `Meta-Mask`. We can store that user info along with its `username` (the default username in fabric is `user1`, `user2`) with `password-phrase`.During user login, it will ask for user's private key or the unique password-phrase generated for its account. The certificates will be stored in `hfc-keystore` (the default dir used in Hyperledger fabric). Whenever a transaction is executed by that user say user `akshay.sood`, we will set the context of that user to `fabric-client` (Please correct if I am wrong in this case).

Here, My questions/queries are:

> 1.) What do you prefer (email/password or private/public keys and why?).
>   2.) If you prefer 2nd mechanism then how will you protect user keys and certificates stored in `hfc-keystore` dir. I mean it can be hacked or data can be stolen by hacker.
>   3.) How to recover user private/public key and certificate if it is deleted mistakenly from `hfc-dir`.
>   4.) Would you prefer using `password-phrase`? if no, what do you prefer?

Edits are welcome.
Please let me know if you have any suggestion/improvements

Comment: Hello, what have you done in the end? I am also doing a application where I need username / passwort authentication in a angular frontend. Now I am struggling to do this. Maybe you can help me here

Comment: @BlockchainProgrammer I am following a similar use case. Any leads or challenges you have encountered would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a choice of your preference, convenience & business needs. You can use either or both approaches in combination. Asking the user to keep or manage his private keys calls for a managed wallet. However, IMHO, if you are concerned about leakage or loss of private keys then you would need a Hardware Security Module that is specifically designed for this purpose.

P.S. Fabric & its examples store the keys in hfc folder for simplicity, although not recommended in real cases.

Comment: Thanks arnab. I think you missed to answer 3rd query.